# Trying to function a button in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a database that is functioning well, when I add a user to it, the database gets updated.
I was trying to update a specific column in the table through a button, but I'm getting redirected to a `404 | NOT FOUND` page.
This is my database, I'm trying to change the `activity_mood` from `0` to `1` by pressing a button.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('NFCnum')->unique();
        $table->string('student_id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->boolean('activity_mood');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This also how the route is added in my `web.php`

```php
Route::post('/students/{student}/activateSavingMood', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@activateSavingMood')->name('students.activateSavingMood');
```

And this is my controller:

```php
public function activateSavingMood(Student $student)
{
    $student->activity_mood = 1;
    $student->save();
    
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Student saving mood activated successfully!');
}
```

And this is my `students.blade.php` for the button:

```xml
@foreach ($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $student->student_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->email }}</td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST"action="{{ route('students.activateSavingMood', $student) }}">
                @csrf
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary activate-btn" name="activate">Activate Saving Mood</button>
            </form>    
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I can't get why it is not redirecting me to the right page or neither changing the value in the database.

Note:
My directory is as follows:

```
resources
  - views
    - home
      - students.blade.php
```

I tried to link it to another blade, but it still redirects me to the `NOT FOUND` page.

Comment: In your Browser, right-click and inspect your `Activate Saving Mood` element, and look at the `<form>` that wraps it to see what the `action` equates to. It _should_ be something like `http://localhost:8000/students/1/activateSavingMood`. Then, in your terminal, run `php artisan tinker`, followed by `Student::findOrFail(1)` (replacing `1` with whatever was in the URL). Does that code work? `findOrFail()` triggers an `HTTP 404` when it fails, so you might be hitting that.

Comment: Some other things to try: A) `{{ route('students.activateSavingMood', ['id' => $student->id]) }}`, **or** B) change your Route to `Route::post('/students/{student}/activateSavingMood', ...)`, then `public function activateSavingMood(Student $student) { ... }`, and remove that `Student::findOrFail()` line (and import your `Student` model via `use App\Models\Student;` at the top of your Controller) and finally change your `action` to `action="{{ route('students.activateSavingMood', $student) }}"`

Comment: [The student id needs to be passed as an array](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes) in the route

Comment: I got this error when I changed in the controller as @TimLewis told me : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `students` (`activity_mood`, `NFCnum`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, o6pBB8oI, 2023-04-28 16:39:06, 2023-04-28 16:39:06))

Comment: That means it's trying to create a new Student instead of editing an existing one, which means your URL isn't correct. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76131094/edit) to show your new code so we can help debug it; I said you need to change your Route, your Controller **AND** your form; did you change all 3 or just your Controller?

Comment: I assumed you did, but your comment says *"I got this error when I changed in the **controller**"*, but nothing about the Route or View. That looks correct, but once again, what is the URL you're `POST`-ing to that's triggering the error?

Comment: This is what I got https://ibb.co/Tcn18QQ

Comment: Well all that is saying is that you don't have a `students` row in your database with an `id` of 1. Should you? Is `http://localhost:8000/students/1/activateSavingMood` the actual URL? If you run `Student::pluck('id')->toArray()`, is `1` in the list of `id`s` returned? This is basic debugging... For `Student $student`, or `Student::findOrFail()` to work, there needs to be a record in your database with that `id`...

Comment: It exists https://ibb.co/FHs11hF

Comment: But `Student::findOrFail(1)` triggers a `ModelNotFound` exception?? That's... Odd. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76131094/edit) and include your `Student.php` Model? Only thing I can think of is that you changed your `protected $primaryKey` to something that isn't `id`... (since both `Student $student` and `Student::findOrFail(1)` will execute `SELECT * FROM students WHERE {primary_key} = 1`)

Comment: OMG Thank you, I was using student_id as a primary key while my database was using only the id.

Comment: Sweet! I was initially going to ask why you had both `id` and `student_id` on your table, but there are cases where you want control over the non-primary `id` (i.e. non-sequential numbers, random-generated strings, etc.). But anyway, you should be able to use either `id` or `student_id` with your original code (just be sure to use the same one in both spots, `protected $primaryKey = 'student_id';`, and `route(..., $student->student_id)`), or you can re-configure your code to work with my suggestion, docs for reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding. Cheers! 